# Cell layout right after dequeueReusableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Can I assume that after getting a cell from `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell()` the cell will have all it's contents sizes (specifically - will be laid out) and I can safely access f.e. the width of a label that's residing inside the cell?

It seems to be working in my project, but I wanted to be totally shure, but cannot find relevant information in docs.

Comment: what you want to exactly ?

Comment: I want to access my label's width so I can decide if I need to hide some other buttons or not. The label is a subview of the cells main view.

Comment: at where you need label width ?

Comment: I would love to use it in the `tableView(cellForRow:)` right after I dequeue a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more reliable:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // do your setup tasks here
}
```

Comment: I guess that is a better solution, but its not the direct answer to the question, so I'll accept the other one, ok?

Comment: @dontgonearthecastle - the results may be different when using fixed-height vs dynamic-height cells... When I run a quick test using a cell with variable number of lines in a `UILabel`, I get (for example) `(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)` for the cell frame in `cellForRow` and `(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 40.3333333333333)` for that same cell in `willDisplay`

Comment: Well, that food for thoughts. I think willDisplay was meant to be the place to do things like this, so its slways better to keep to it ;) and thank for the detailed research! ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get label width which exist in cell....then using tag property you can get label and its width..

Comment: The thing is - can I be sure all the frames and sizes are correct? Or if there's something that I don't understand? :p I mean - f.e. you cannot initalise geometry-related things in `viewDidLoad` method. So can I initialise geometry-related things in `tableView(cellForRow)` right after I get the cell from `dequeueReusableCell`?

Comment: No, I just couldnt find any confirmation if it's safe to do so

Comment: @dontgonearthecastle why did you unaccept my answer ?

Comment: Because I beleive DonMag's answer provides much better way to solve this problem. I know that your answer is a direct answer to the question but he made some research to prove that there's a better way to achieve what I wanted. No offence ;)